# Editing Embed after Button Click in Discordjs

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to create a bot where after a button is pressed it edits the embed, showing the selected player in the relevant team. My problem is that I have tried to look at several options on internet and particularly stack overflow but to no avail. So I am asking instead. I am attaching the code below. It prints "I am here", which I added just to make sure the button click was being registered but does not edit the embed.

P.S. I am not great at Discord.js or JS in general so apologies if I have done something dumb.

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Match Maker 3v3')
    .setDescription('Lobby ' + gameID)
    .addField('Team 1', team1.join('\n'))
    .addField('Team 2', team2.join('\n'))
    .addField('Players to choose from', players.join(' '));

message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]}).then((m) => {
    const row = new MessageActionRow();
    for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        row.addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId(`${i}`)
                .setLabel(`${playerNames.standard[i]}`)
                .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
        );
    }

    const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
        max: 4,
    });

    collector.on('collect', interaction => {
        interaction.reply(`Clicked button ${interaction.customId}`);
        team1.push(players[parseInt(interaction.customId)]);
        players.splice(interaction.customId, 1);
        const embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#ffffff')
            .setTitle('Match Maker 3v3')
            .setDescription('Lobby ' + gameID)
            .addField('Team 1', team1.join('\n'))
            .addField('Team 2', team2.join('\n'))
            .addField('Players to choose from', players.join(' '));
        m.edit({embed: [embed2]});
        console.log('I am here');
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the the collector

Interaction.message.edit({embeds:[])

Comment: I did earlier, that wasn't working either. But maybe I was implementing it incorrectly I don't know